# How to stop Calendar automatically adding invites?

Tags: calendar, siri

Whenever I add a new event titled "Golf" in my calendar, it finds an old invitee from a Siri app.  If I'm not super diligent and delete this, the invitation is sent.  How do I permanently delete this old request?

Comment: I've turned off everything I can find about notifications and Siri's use of...

Comment: This information should be added to your Question itself, rather than being posted in a Comment. Use the "edit" button you'll see below the Question text.